# Using z-index to put some objects behind, others in front

Tags: html, css, z-index

I've got a horizontal navigation bar on my page which is pushed down a few pixels to overlap with the content of the div below. I want to have some of the links placed behind the background of the content div, but I can't figure out a way to keep some of the links (such as the link to the current page) in front. Here is what I have:

```
<div id="header">
    <ul id="nav">
    <li><a href="index.php" class="index">index</a></li>
    <li><a href="project.php" class="project">project[]</a></li>
    <li><a href="contact.php" class="contact">contact</a></li>
    <li><a href="about.php" class="about">about</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div id="content">
</div>
```

Relevant CSS:

```
div#content {
        background:#444;
        border-radius:15px;
        padding:40px 30px 30px 30px;
        clear:left
    }
div#header {
        position: relative;
        margin-left:20px;
        top: 13px;
    }


ul#nav {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    white-space: nowrap;

}

ul#nav li {
    display:inline;
}

ul#nav a {
    text-decoration:none;
    color: #444;
    font-size: 30px;
}
```

I'm using the class of each link to determine if it points to the current page, so I'd like that link to stick out. The problem is that the stacking context for each of these is inside the div or ul.

Comment: Sorry, I was having trouble accessing my CSS.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/PNC7g/ : I tried it on IE7+ and Firefox 9.

The idea is to set `position: relative; z-index: 1` to the `#content` and to every `link`  and the content has the  property `top: -13px` defined. Even if they share the same z-index order position, `#content` is defined after the list of links (inside the markup), so it will overlap the navigation menu.

But if you later set `z-index: 2` to a link (with a special class, like `.current`), the selected item will be able to overlap the div.

Comment: +1 for using z-index values 1 and 2 rather than silly values such as 1000 and 2000, like you often see used by people who don't understand z-indexes.

Comment: @MrLister I usually set a step-by-10 z-index, just in case something else should be inserted later across two positioned elements (and without touching other z-indexes). for this example 1 and 2 is enough to make the example clear.